# Use to Fiddler trace a third party webservice call in ASP.NET MVC action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fiddler

Using Fiddler I want to trace a call to an external webservice made in the body of an ASP.NET MVC action method.

When I run this code as a console application or Nunit test I can see the request/response to the external server using Fiddler;

```
[Test]
public void TestWebservice() 
{   
    MyWebService checker = new MyWebService();
    i = checker.GetAge("bob");
    Assert.True(i >= 0); 
}
```

When I call the webservice from an ASP.MVC action method I can't see the underlying request to the external server, although I can see the request to the action method from my browser;

```
public ActionResult MakeTheCall(string name)
{
    MyWebService checker = new MyWebService();
    i = checker.GetAge(name);
    return View();
}
```

Is there a way for Fiddler to show the request/response to a third party webservice made in the body of an ASP.NET MVC action method?

Comment: Is the third party webservice hosted on localhost or a remote host?

Comment: One question, if the network fails to respond when you're testing your Web Service, are you expecting your test to unit test to fail? What happens if it's simply a network problem and your unit tests start failing? Is that what you intend?

Comment: @sandyiit - the third party webservice is on a remote host.  @JamieDixon yes, if the network is down the test will fail.  Don't worry about this - This code is just to illustrate calling the webservice another way, I could equally have put this as a console app.

Comment: Can you try setting Fiddler as a proxy,  and use the Fiddler proxy when you call the webservice

Comment: details about how to set it up at http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp

Comment: GlobalProxySelection.Select = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888); added to the Application_Start method in a ASP.NET MVC web application works, thanks @sandyiit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the answer from comments to Answer section:

Can you try setting Fiddler as a proxy, and use the Fiddler proxy when you call the webservice

details about how to set it up at http://fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp

Comment: GlobalProxySelection.Select = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888); added to the Application_Start method in a ASP.NET MVC web application works

Comment: GlobalProxySelection is now deprecated - use `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Fiddler as a reverse proxy and have it forward local calls on a given port to a remote server on a different port. So, you configure your app to call localhost:8888 and Fiddler forwards to remote:80.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp

Another option is Charles which has easier configuration for this setup.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/